# Query against Postgres runs forever over JDBC, but finishes in 1 Minute through pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, spring-batch, postgresql-11

We have a pgsql function that inserts rows into the db based on a complex query. The database is postgres 11, on azure single server (16 cores, 32gb memory). The last problematic run would insert 6000 rows.

Yes, the function's query is likely not very efficient, inflating memory usage with inneffective joins and sort/distinct, etc etc. That we can deal with.

Now, when the function is being executed by our spring boot application over JDBC, it runs extremely long (20 minutes, sometimes inifitely).
The application uses the java tomcat connection pool on ~25 idling connectings being reused.
But when we run the same pgsql function through pgAdmin, it succeedes every time, in about 1 minute!
It also works when executing it against a local postgres instance.

I would expect to have the same issues, regardless of whether we execute the query through pgAdmin or the application?

**What could be the reason for having extremely inconsistent execution times?**
If memory/swapping is the issue (e.g. because low work_mem), shouldn't every connection have the same issues?

The executed statement is `SELECT * FROM create_change_reviews(10);`

Here is the function, to get an idea what it does. The select statements are reduced a bit. It shouldn't matter, as optimizing the query is not what I am asking for.

```sql
CREATE
    OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_change_reviews(rev integer)
    RETURNS TABLE
            (
                created  int,
                type     text,
                duration interval
            )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$function$
DECLARE
    created_reviews
                    int;
    start_time
                    timestamp;
BEGIN
    SELECT clock_timestamp()
    INTO start_time;

    WITH
        relevant_documents as (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                mc.id           as mc_id,
                mc.oid          as mc_oid,
                mc.role_name    as importance_role
            FROM so_document_version dv
                     JOIN so_module m ON dv.id = m.document_version_id and m.import_id = rev
                     JOIN so_module_changedescription mc ON
                        m.id = mc.module_id AND mc.importance IN ('must know')
        ),
        changes_with_effect AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                u.id as user_id,
                rd.mc_oid as oid
            FROM relevant_documents rd
                     JOIN so_user u ON u.id > 0
                     JOIN so_user_role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
                     JOIN so_role r ON ur.role_id = r.id AND rd.importance_role = r.name
                     JOIN so_effect_role er
                          ON per.role_name = rd.importance_role = r.name
                     JOIN so_module_change_effect mce ON mce.effect_id = er.effect_id AND rd.mc_id = mce.change_id
        ),
        changes_no_effect AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                u.id as user_id,
                rd.mc_oid as oid
            FROM relevant_documents rd
                     LEFT JOIN so_module_change_effect ce on rd.mc_id = ce.change_id
                     JOIN so_user u ON u.id > 0
                     JOIN so_user_role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
                     JOIN so_role r ON ur.role_id = r.id AND rd.importance_role = r.name
            WHERE ce.effect_id is null
        ),
        all_changes AS (
            SELECT user_id, oid FROM changes_with_effect
            UNION
            SELECT user_id, oid FROM changes_no_effect
        )
    INSERT
    INTO so_module_change_review(id, read, user_id, change_oid, created, created_by, updated, updated_by)
    SELECT nextval('hibernate_sequence'),
           false,
           nuvr.user_id,
           nuvr.oid,
           current_timestamp,
           -1,
           current_timestamp,
           -1
    FROM (
             SELECT DISTINCT user_id, oid
             FROM all_changes ac
         ) nuvr ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

    GET DIAGNOSTICS created_reviews = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE
        NOTICE 'Created % module reviews', created_reviews;

    RETURN QUERY SELECT created_reviews, 'module', clock_timestamp() - start_time;
END
$function$
;
```

for completeness, here is the Spring Batch `Tasklet`, which does some questionable stuff (unboxing the underlying connection of the session)

```java
public class CreateReviewsTask implements Tasklet {

    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        SessionImpl session = unboxSession();
        Connection connection = session.connection();
        boolean prevAutoCommitValue = connection.getAutoCommit();
        connection.setAutoCommit(true); // disable transactions
        try {
            execute(connection, contribution, chunkContext);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Database task failed", e);
            contribution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            connection.setAutoCommit(prevAutoCommitValue);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private SessionImpl unboxSession() {
        Object delegate = entityManager.getDelegate();
        if (delegate instanceof SessionImpl) {
            return (SessionImpl)delegate;
        }

        return (SessionImpl)entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }

    protected void execute(Connection connection, StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws SQLException {
        long importId = Long.parseLong(chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get(IMPORT_ID).toString());
        try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM create_change_reviews(" + importId + ");")) {
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int creationCount = rs.getInt("created");
                    String type = rs.getString("type");
                    String duration = rs.getString("duration");
                    logger.info("Created {} {} reviews in {}", creationCount, type, duration);
                    contribution.incrementFilterCount(creationCount);
                    contribution.incrementWriteCount(creationCount);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Error creating reviews", e);
            throw new ImportException("Error creating reviews. " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

PS:

- The database usage is low (cpu, memory, disk), no spikes.
- I hope this question does not sound too fuzzy. Please tell me if/what relevant information I might have missed

Comment: Is this query using a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`? Did you try collecting an execution plan for a slow execution with auto_explain?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, it uses PreparedStatement. But the function call is super simple anyway: `SELECT * FROM create_change_reviews();` and only returns two rows (the insertion counts).

We kinda know where the inefficiencies are in the query, but what really concerns us is that the execution times vary so much.
Without understanding that, I fear that optimizing might just postphone the issue

Comment: Is autocommit turned off in JDBC?

Comment: It could be a generic plan used by a query in the function. Try `ALTER FUNCTION create_change_reviews() SET plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan;` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, it is turned off. I guess pgAdmin has it turned on, that could be a difference

Comment: The previous statement is wrong: For this specific query the autocommit is temporarily activated on the connection. So its the same as in pgAdmin

Comment: Use auto_explain with log_min_duration to get the plan for the JDBC query. It is best to turn on auto_explain.log_analyze as well, but that will impose some amount of overhead to every query.

Comment: Please revise the quetion to include the queries as they are run in pgAdmin and the Java code that is performing the same work. If it were just a block of SQL, then it shouldn't matter from which client it's run. From the described behavior, it appears that the Java code might be performing the insert row-by-row instead of as a set.

Comment: @JohnH I added the function. To be honest, I can't see how the sql or the function itself would be the issue. But I think you are right with your conclusion, I guess something in the java code does not work as expected. (IMO autocommit=true works tho, since another job uses the same code to do a VACUUM, which can't run in a transaction)